# Posting multiple photos to Instagram app using UIDocumentInteractionController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, instagram

i am experienced developer but new on Swift.
My purpose is to draw some images in my iOS app programmatically and post them to Instagram app.

After some researches I found below two methods do this.

First one is UIActivityViewController. This way works very well with one image but Instagram app doesn't show up in popover view when I pass two or more images.

The second way is using UIDocumentInteractionController. With this way I can pass image path as URL. But with this URL I can pass only one image path to the class. My code is below.

```
    let instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://app")


    if(UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramURL! as URL)) {
        let imagePost = imageToPost

        let fullPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("insta.igo")
        let a = try! UIImagePNGRepresentation(imagePost)?.write(to: fullPath!, options: .atomic)

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
        self.docController.uti = "com.instagram.exclusivegram"
        let igImageHookFile = fullPath
        self.docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: igImageHookFile! as URL)
        self.docController.annotation = ["InstagramCaption":"Text"]
        self.docController.presentOpenInMenu(from: rect, in: self.view, animated: true)

    } else {
        print("no instagram found")
    }
```

Is there any way to post more than one image without using camera roll?

Comment: Hi did you get anything?
I also want to post more than one image without using camera roll.

Comment: Not exactly. I think it is not possible just because of Instagram app doesn't support this.